# output "sed" command to variable

Tags: shell, ubuntu, sed, terminal, newline

I am writing a shell script on Ubuntu and use the 
`sed` command to replace all occurences of `TOREPLACE`
with a `newline \n`.

```
sed 's/TOREPLACE/\n/g' /home/user/source.txt
```

This works great but what I actually want to do is 
to assign the output from above to a variable:

```
TTT=$(sed 's/TOREPLACE/\n/g' /home/user/source.txt)
echo $TTT
```

`echo $TTT` does not deliver the expected output... when I try to replace
`TOREPLACE` with an other string everything works fine.

When I redirect `sed` to a file all newline replacements work too.

Whats wrong with the variable assignment above?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow (S.O.) Please remeber to read the FAQs, http://tinyurl.com/2vycnvr , vote for good Q/A  by using the gray triangles,  http://i.imgur.com/kygEP.png , and to accept the answer that best solves your problem, if any, by pressing the checkmark sign , http://i.imgur.com/uqJeW.png . Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "$TTT"
```

should work fine as well.

Comment: Well indeed that was the problem :)
This seems to makes an important difference...

Thank you both!!!

Comment: @JoeFrizz: You should almost always quote variables.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any problem with the variable assignment. Try
    `echo "${TTT}"`